# How can I make a loop to perform action on Neighbours of my start box in python?

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a grid using for loop and pygame :

[image]

and I have also connected it to a 2d-array. I have converted x, y into rows and columns according to the blocks.

now the green block represents the start position and I have to perform actions on its neighbors i.e all blocks touching it(even the corner blocks)

I wanted to know is there a more efficient solution to this as currently I am just storing them one-by-one in a list and then perform actions on it.

Like a loop or something like that.

and to get the row and column of each it takes a lot of code so please help I am a beginner.

Till now I have done something like this(I know this is the worst way)

```
self.neighboursx.append(self.start_point_column)
self.neighboursy.append(self.start_point_row - 1)

self.neighboursx.append(self.start_point_column + 1)
self.neighboursy.append(self.start_point_row - 1)

self.neighboursx.append(self.start_point_column + 1)
self.neighboursy.append(self.start_point_row)

self.neighboursx.append(self.start_point_column - 1)
self.neighboursy.append(self.start_point_row + 1)

self.neighboursx.append(self.start_point_column)
self.neighboursy.append(self.start_point_row + 1)

self.neighboursx.append(self.start_point_column - 1)
self.neighboursy.append(self.start_point_row + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop through a 2D array, you could do something like:

```
for col in range(number_of_columns:
    for row in range(number_of_rows):
        do_something(col, row)
```

For your neighbour checking function:

```
def do_something(col, row):  # e.g. count neighbours of a boolean 2D array dd
    count = 0
    for x in range(-1, 2): # -1, 0, 1
        for y in range(-1, 2):
            try:
                if dd[col +x][row + y]: 
                    count += 1
            except IndexError:  # cell is outside array
                pass
        # but we don't want to count ourselves,
        if dd[col][row]:
            count -= 1
    # now do something with the count
    …
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer, Your answer has solved my problem, But how did you come up with so good solution, have you already worked on a project like this before? please tell me, as I am a beginner these tips will be really useful,

Comment: and lastly I wanted to know what will this part do (to be sure) "if dd[col +x][row + y]:" is this returning True?

Comment: Hey bro I just tested the code but it gives error "IndexError: list index out of range" in same line as the if statement in the function. Kindly help again

Comment: Hi @SauravPrashar, I have edited to code to include exception handling. Regarding `if dd[col +x][row + y]:` this is just an example, it is not clear from your question on what you need to do. In this case I'm assuming that dd is a 2D boolean array, so the variable `count` will be incremented if the cell is `True`. If your array contains some other object, then you can use `dd[col +x][row + y]` to refer to the object and inspect its attributes.

Comment: Now what I did was that Instead of that conditional in the loop I am putting it in a list directlybecause I need those coordinates in many functions

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of the neighbour indices:

```py
neighbours = [(-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1)]
```

respectively

```py
neighbours = [(i, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3) if i != j]
```

And use the indices in a for loop:

```py
for x, y in neighbours:
    col = self.start_point_column + x
    row = self.start_point_row + y
    if 0 <= col < columns and 0 <= row < rows: 
        # do something with "row" and "col"
```